# JPA Hibernate:@Transactional Save entity in the exception catch block

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, exception, spring-data-jpa

I am doing two operations in a single transaction and my code looks like

```
**Model looks like**

@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class CarDTO {
  
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "model_id")
  private String model;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "cars_sheds",
      joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = car_id) },
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "shed_id") })
  private Set<Shed> sheds = new HashSet<>();

  .
  .
  .etc
}


**Service method looks like**

  @Transactional(rollbackOn = {Exception.class, CrudException.class})
  public CarDTO sendToShed(String id, String shedId) {

    CarDTO dbCar = getById(id);
    Shed shed = shedService.getShedById(shedId);
    dbCar.getSheds().add(shed);
    CarDTO updatedCar = patch(dbCar, id);

    try {
      shedService.sendCarToShed(updatedCar, shedId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logData('car_id','shed_id', 401, 'exception while saving');
      throw new CrudException("Exception while sending project to SmartconX");
    }
    return updatedCar;
  }

  public void logData(String carId, String shedId, int httpStatusCode, String responseMessage) {
      LogDTO log = new LogDTO(carId, shedId, httpStatusCode, responseMessage);
      logsRepository.save(log);
  }
```

**success case**: first I am saving entity before try block and try block executes without issues.

**exception case**: first I am saving entity and when try block throughs exception in the catch block I need to save the error into a logs table. But because of @trans - rollback the entity and error log both were gets rollbacked.

if I remove @Transaction on top of the method I am able to save logs but the entity saved which should not.

**What I need**: In the exception case I need to roll back the entity but need to log failed response into logs table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to maintain a separate transaction for `public void logData()` method using @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW).

Now sendToShed() and logData() will have separate transaction.

Comment: Already I tried this but no use.